# GitHub, automatically create PR for another branch

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

#### Background

> TEAM1 is working on a new branch `DEV_NEW_FEATURE` (which is initially
>   branched form `DEV`) that is going into production in 2 weeks. TEAM2
>   will work on branch `DEV` that will not be going into production
>   until a few months from now.

#### Question

> What is the best strategy to keep all changes from `DEV` out of
>   `DEV_NEW_FEATURE`, but ensure that all work in `DEV_NEW_FEATURE` is being merged into `DEV`?

#### Possible Solution

> DEV_NEW_FEATURE -> DEV -> STAGING
>
> DEV_NEW_FEATURE -> STAGING_NEW_FEATURE -> PROD

However, this would require TEAM1 to merge into `DEV` for every change going into `DEV_NEW_FEATURE`. Is there a way to potentially automate the PR creation of `DEV_NEW_FEATURE` being merged into `DEV`?